# Prometheus relabeling configureation incremental counter

Tags: regex, label, prometheus

I'm trying to scrape metrics from my ec2 machines.
Those machines has a complex name due to Auto scaling group.
For example:

- `ProjectName/project-name-dev-cluster/project-name-dev-LaunchTemplate`
- `ProjectName/project-name-prod-cluster/project-name-prod-LaunchTemplate`
- `ProjectName/project-name-prod-cluster/project-name-prod-LaunchTemplate`

Beyond their name, I need to relabel the names in the relabel_configs section in the `prometheus.yaml`: I need to rename those machines to look something like this: `project_name-environment-counter` so, for example:

- `project_name-dev-1`
- `project_name-prod-1`
- `project_name-prod-2`

so basically I need to count how many dev and prod machines are.
I've tried something but noting worked.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this: unless counter you want to use is already a part of machine's name (or any other label) you cannot achieve described goal.

Prometheus' [`relabel_config`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config) can only use labels of the target (`metric_relabel_configs` can also use labels of the time series itself, but it doesn't help here). And those labels are limited to the target of relabeling. So no way of knowing what how many other machines with similar names are present, nor iterating with some kind of variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer !! 
I guess I need to change the ec2 machine's name to do this then.